# How to print blog post content in the source code of the page while importing '.md' files dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, svelte, sveltekit

I'm putting together a blog with Sveltekit and markdown files. And my blog url structure differs from where my original writings in .md format are saved.

I can get the posts from the folder using dynamic import as:

```
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';

    //get current post name
    const pageName = $page.url.pathname;
    const postUrl = pageName.split('/');
    var lastSegment = postUrl.pop() || postUrl.pop(); // handle potential trailing slash
</script>

{#await import(`../../posts/${lastSegment}.md`) then value}
    <svelte:component this={value.default} />
{/await}
```

and they are shown on the page but not in the source code. I'm sure it'll have an impact on SEO. So, my issue is, how can I display the content in the page's source?

p.s. I'm also using MDSVEX.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "source code"?

Comment: Source code means source code of the page. The blog posts content is invisible while rest of tags are visible. CTRL+U for source code of any page.